# UIButton changes size when pushing view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton

I have a static tableView with one section and one row in that section. That tableview has a footerView which has a UIButton in it. All looks as expected (I positioned everything in the footerView on the tableViewController's viewDidLoad), until I click the row of the tableView. This causes a segue to a new viewController - the moment it begins to push, the UIButton changes size. I don't edit the frame of the button when pushing the view controller, and if I try setting the frame of the button on viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear back to what it originally was set to, it remains the same. I've also checked to ensure the footerView isn't changing size - it stays the same as it was initially set.

I can't post images yet, but I've uploaded screenshots to imgur:

Before tapping the tableView row:
[image]

After tapping the tableView row:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the Autosizing of the button
[image]